# Obtain backtrace from window.addEventListener('error') in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am trying to log errors on devices, that don't have a builtin javascript console (e.g. mobile). In the process I was trying to capture errors using `window.addEventListener('error', (event)=>{...})`.

In Firefox, the entry `event.error` gives access to full information about the error. In Chrome however, `event.error` is always `null`. Similarly, the equivalent error-object that is passed as one of the arguments to `window.onerror` is present in Firefox, but missing in Chrome.

Is this expected behavior? Is there some reliable cross-browser method of accessing the backtrace information?

### Example

Execute in the console, e.g. on this site.

```
window.addEventListener('error', (err) => {
    for(const key in err) {
        console.log(key,'=',err[key]);
    }
});
// Chrome doesn't capture errors produced directly in the console,
// so we use a timeout.
window.setTimeout(()=>{ noSuchVariable; }, 100)
```

I obtain:

```
VM5685:3 isTrusted = true
VM5685:3 message = Script error.
VM5685:3 filename = 
VM5685:3 lineno = 0
VM5685:3 colno = 0
VM5685:3 error = null
...
```

I obtain the same result in private mode, i.e. it is not related to extensions.

Firefox give the much more helpful result:

```
sTrusted = true debugger eval code:3:17
message = ReferenceError: noSuchVariable is not defined debugger eval code:3:17
filename = debugger eval code debugger eval code:3:17
lineno = 8 debugger eval code:3:17
colno = 25 debugger eval code:3:17
error = ReferenceError: "noSuchVariable is not defined"
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you edit a live snippet into your question that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added an example.

Comment: If you type code directly into the console, there can be weird results (its execution context is pretty strange), but if you change the callback function body to `console.log(err.error);` and run the code in a normal `<script>`, the message looks to be displayed as desired

Comment: @CertainPerformance That seems to have been the origin. I was using it in a console, since I was working on a bookmarklet; But thankfully when invoked as `javascript:` URI, the expected behavior occurs. Can you turn your comment into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432262/obtain-backtrace-from-window-addeventlistenererror-in-chrome?noredirect=1#comment105050500_59432262), the issue was caused by using the Chrome developer console, which interferes with error handling.

The error data is correctly given however, if the error is thrown inside a timer, or inside a script executed by typing a `javascript:` URL.